# How can I load static content using NGINX?

Tags: php, caching, curl, nginx, proxy

I'm struggling trying to load static contents on my page using NGINX, and below is my current configuration. My goal is to make my page load faster that's why I want to load the static content through NGINX, but that I notice the loading time of my page is the same.

---

## Configuration

File Path : `etc/nginx/default`

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name default;
    root /home/forge/site/public;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://43.35.49.160/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
        expires 1M;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # CSS and Javascript
    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        expires 1y;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # cache.appcache, your document html and data
    location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
      expires -1;
      access_log logs/static.log; # I don't usually include a static log
    }

    # Feed
    location ~* \.(?:rss|atom)$ {
      expires 1h;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    #include folder/file-name.conf;
 
}
```

---

## cURL TEST

`curl -X GET -I  http://45.33.69.160/`

---

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.3
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Sat, 09 May 2015 15:09:02 GMT
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkVNZ205RjhuNWI2aUtEOUxRbjJSdUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiN2RtSlJVZUZ6ZFpWNUNETElZOTNuK1ZzQW5Lcmw5UTVKVmo1REFRT2w0cVJoS3IxUitaOWNKYkh5NERrQXZ5VXpjbmNkSlZ0NTFwXC9XNGVxQ0xVYXlBPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI4Yjk4NjI1YjdjMDgxMzJiOTk4MzIxNmUzOTMxM2JiNDY2OTc4ZTZkNzI4Y2IxNjZlYmViNTAyYmZhY2ZlYjYzIn0%3D; expires=Sat, 09-May-2015 17:09:02 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Ik5zKzRcLzBEWE5mUjVhUlwvVE9GeWk3Zz09IiwidmFsdWUiOiJCT0pqaWFFQlhCdlJNTGlMZEV3dlg0K2RjTEVrY1dpNU5TbzB6NFBnMzU5Q2J6dzV5S25GR2pERVpKY2taYndOMG1ZRFcxUUZqQmFrUEREKzdCaFltZz09IiwibWFjIjoiMmJhYjBmNmMzMWQwNTIwMTFjMGFiZGJkY2MyNWRiYzAzMzU3OGU4MDliZGFlZWQzNzQ3MTNmOTcyYzY0NjMyNiJ9; expires=Sat, 09-May-2015 17:09:02 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
```

---

## Benchmark TEST

I tried to load one of my file `css/bootstrap.min.css`

`ab -c 20 -n 1000 http://45.33.69.160/css/bootstrap.min.css`

**Result**:

```
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1638069 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 45.33.69.160 (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Completed 600 requests
Completed 700 requests
Completed 800 requests
Completed 900 requests
Completed 1000 requests
Finished 1000 requests


Server Software:        nginx/1.6.3
Server Hostname:        45.33.69.160
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /css/bootstrap.min.css
Document Length:        78358 bytes

Concurrency Level:      20
Time taken for tests:   0.239 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      78593000 bytes
HTML transferred:       78358000 bytes
Requests per second:    4184.42 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       4.780 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.239 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          321157.98 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    2   0.7      2       3
Processing:     1    3   0.8      3       5
Waiting:        0    1   0.8      1       4
Total:          3    5   0.7      5       7

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      5
  66%      5
  75%      5
  80%      5
  90%      6
  95%      6
  98%      6
  99%      7
 100%      7 (longest request)
```

---

**Note:** `Time taken for tests:   0.239 seconds`

The loading time of the content seem to be the same with/without my static content configuration. Isn't it suppose to be faster ?

---

For some reason, the configuration doesn't seem to be set at all.
Can someone please point out what I did wrong here ?
Suggestions or Feedbacks will be much appreciated !

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @AlexeyTen :  
I tested the loading time of one of my file (/css/custom.css), the time to load the file with and without the configuration seem to be the same. Which mean my configuration doesn't take any effect. I'm very curious to know why.

Comment: @AlexeyTen : Do you have any suggestion/feedbacks for me ?

Comment: Still see no problem. If you try to test caching then `ab` is wrong tool. Your `curl` loads only html and doesn't load any static files, so there is nothing to say.

Comment: BTW, have you restarted nginx?

Comment: @AlexeyTen : Since ab and cUrl is the wrong tool ? How would I test to see if my setting is work ? Any suggestions interm of how do I test it?

Comment: ab is about stress test, it ignores any caching headers so not suitable to test if your caching config is good or bad. curl is better, but I still don't see anything that show your config doesn't work

Comment: Hmm... I know that I reload my NGinx already, but I will do it a again. Is Chrome dev help in this case ? :(